# Where does my p-trap start and end

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, clog

I have a clogged kitchen sink and most videos show removing the p-trap if using a plunger does not work. However, my p-trap looks different than most videos I've seen. Usually the two "screws" would be located in and around the blue box. However, the pipes appear to be glued together. So this leads me to believe I must remove the entire section within the red square.

Question: Am I correct in assuming the entire red section will need to be removed to start looking at clearing the drain?

Notes: The clear pipe (green line) is connected to the dishwasher and I also did noticed a small drip start to occur when the sink was clogged (purple circle)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct - that's a glued trap which are much more of a pain to work with than slip-joint traps, since there are less places to take them apart.

The clear pipe from the dishwasher should loop high up to the underside of the counter. If it does not do that somewhere out of this picture, you should correct that when reassembling, if possible.

The purple-circled drip suggests that you might want a new slip joint washer or gasket when reassembling. They are inexpensive replacement parts, and they can harden up and fail to seal well after years of service.